# Useful Xcode DEBUG commands to use in console

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, debug-backtrace

I've been wondering but haven't found anywhere an useful list of commands that are useful in Xcode.

One I know, and I use a lot is Backtrace which the input command is `bt` , after you encounter an app crash after uncaught exceptions it sometimes gives an int where the problem could be.

Can you share more useful commands that become handy and could let us interact with the debugger and the app itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find it in Apple documentation: [Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)

or check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html

Comment: ohh thank you, didn't knew Apple gave such detailed documentation on that subject. ;)